# how to add custom error page when no interent is detected in android web app

Tags: java, android

iam begineer in nadroid development , i tried this logic

```
    ConnectivityManager cManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nInfo = cManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(nInfo!=null && nInfo.isConnected()) {
```

to detect internet and display a error `Toast` but when i  implemented this by disabling my internet, iam getting a white page while showing toast and after displaying the toast iam getting a white page with loading symbol . i would like to change that white page while displaying the `Toast` and i would like to fix the issue that iam getting a white page with loading symbol after displaying the toast.Please help me fixing this issue .

Here is my MainActivity.java Source :

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConnectivityManager cManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nInfo = cManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(nInfo!=null && nInfo.isConnected()) {




            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
            WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("https://mobile-tech2dsk.blogspot.in/");
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new com.example.tech2dsk.tech2dsk.MyAppWebViewClient(){

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    //hide loading image
                    findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //show webview
                    findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }});


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }





    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        /** Inflating the current activity's menu with res/menu/items.xml */
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        /** Getting the actionprovider associated with the menu item whose id is share */
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.share).getActionProvider();

        /** Setting a share intent */
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    /** Returns a share intent */
    private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Convert Website to Android Application");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT," Vist www.AndroidWebViewApp.com if you Want to Convert your Website or Blog to Android Application");
        return intent;

    }


}
```

Comment: Do you want to show some thing other than `Toast`?

Comment: Yes I would like show other than Toast

Comment: Check i'm posted a solution for you.

Comment: would like to fix the issue that iam getting a white page with loading symbol after displaying the toast.Please help me fixing this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your activity_main.xml file

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/ringtone_layout_retry"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:visibility="gone">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Check your connection and try again." />

<Button
android:id="@+id/ringtone_btnRetry"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:text="Retry" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and instead of showing the `Toast`  using this code:

```
LinearLayout ly = (LinearLayout)_view.findViewById(R.id.ringtone_layout_retry);
findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
ly.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: OK will implement this

Comment: would like to fix the issue that iam getting a white page with loading symbol after displaying the toast.Please help me fixing this issue

Comment: did you implement?

Comment: I am implementing , I think the other issue is also due to this

Comment: @Rohith i've updated my answer.I'm sure it can help you.

Comment: this is my main activity file where should i implemnet that